# Trouble with pandas merge function after parsing date columns

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I got the following two dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2012-12-31', '2013-12-31', '9999-12-31'],
                    'value':[4, 5, 6]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2013-12-31', '2012-12-31', '2010-12-31'],
                    'value':[14, 55, 36]})
```

The problem with df1 is that the ['date] column contains a value which can't be directly parsed as timestamp.So I used the following function:

```
def to_datetime(x):
    try:
       res = pd.to_datetime(x)
    except:
       res = x
    return res
```

Then I have the new columns as:

```
df1['date_new'] = df1['date'].apply(to_datetime)
df2['date_new'] = df2['date'].apply(to_datetime)
```

I want to merge the two dataframes on ['date_new'],but there is no matched values.

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, how = 'inner', on = ['date_new'])
```

However,

```
df1['date_new'][0] == df2['date_new'][1]
```

returns **True**.
The full code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

def to_datetime(x):
    try:
        res = pd.to_datetime(x)
    except:
        res = x
    return res

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2012-12-31', '2013-12-31', '9999-12-31'],
                    'value':[4, 5, 6]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2013-12-31', '2012-12-31', '2010-12-31'],
                    'value':[14, 55, 36]})

df1['date_new'] = df1['date'].apply(to_datetime)
df2['date_new'] = df2['date'].apply(to_datetime)

df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, how = 'inner', on = ['date_new'])
```

Please tell me why this happened. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pd.to_datetime` has the handy `errors` argument, which you can set to `coerce`. Then, your code seems to work:

```
df1['date_new'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['date'], errors='coerce')
df2['date_new'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['date'], errors='coerce')

df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, how = 'inner', on = ['date_new'])


>>> df3
       date_x  value_x   date_new      date_y  value_y
0  2012-12-31        4 2012-12-31  2012-12-31       55
1  2013-12-31        5 2013-12-31  2013-12-31       14
```

**NOTE THAT** as your dates are coerced, they will turn up as `NaT` if they do not fit a date format, so these coerced values would match when merged. For example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2012-12-31', '2013-12-31', '9999-12-31','xyz'],
                    'value':[4, 5, 6, 14]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2013-12-31', '2012-12-31', '2010-12-31','sss'],
                    'value':[14, 55, 36, 12]})

df1['date_new'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['date'], errors='coerce')
df2['date_new'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['date'], errors='coerce')

df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, how = 'inner', on = ['date_new'])
```

leads to this:

```
>>> df3
       date_x  value_x   date_new      date_y  value_y
0  2012-12-31        4 2012-12-31  2012-12-31       55
1  2013-12-31        5 2013-12-31  2013-12-31       14
2  9999-12-31        6        NaT         sss       12
3         xyz       14        NaT         sss       12
```

To avoid these, you can merge the subset of the dataframe where `date_new` is not null:

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1.loc[df1.date_new.notnull()], df2.loc[df2.date_new.notnull()], how = 'inner', on = ['date_new'])
```

As to ***Why*** that happened with your code, your function ends up returning a series of `dtype: object` if it finds an unsuitable date:

```
df1['date_new'] = df1['date'].apply(to_datetime)
>>> df1['date_new']
0    2012-12-31 00:00:00
1    2013-12-31 00:00:00
2             9999-12-31
Name: date_new, dtype: object
```

but a series of type `dtype: datetime64[ns]` when all dates are OK:

```
df2['date_new'] = df2['date'].apply(to_datetime)
>>> df2['date_new']
0   2013-12-31
1   2012-12-31
2   2010-12-31
Name: date_new, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

So these don't merge properly

Comment: Thanks!!! Could you please explain why the merge function fails with my  code? I mean, df1['date_new'] and df2['date_new'] contain the same values, but it do not work. The difference is that,  in my code, '9999-12-31' returns a string. However, '9999-12-31' returns 'NaT' in your code.

Comment: I was *just* typing that out, see my update. Also note that the function you wrote actually results in the exact same thing as `pd.to_datetime(df1['date'], errors='coerce')`